# EF 6 Code First Automatic Migrations in a two project solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a two project solution, and ASP.Net MVC project and a DAL project. 
I create my data models in the DAL, enable migrations and am able to migrate the code to the DB properly.

At one time I thought that when I deploy the site to new server and run the ASP.Net MVC project the DB tables would be created properly automagically. And any subsequent db changes would happen automatically too.

Why does this not happen now? My DAL project configuration file has this code in it.

```
public Configuration()
{
   AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
   AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
}
```

Comment: Automatic migrations will only apply migrations that it creates automatically. Any migration you created using the add-migration command will still need to be manually applied. using update-database

Comment: @pquest Not necessarily, you can have it migrate all the time, it depends on the initialiser you set up (e.g. the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`)

Comment: @DavidG I stand corrected. I didn't know about that. However, for the way it is set up above, I am correct, right?

Comment: @pquest Well you are probably right, but the initialiser could also be specified in the `web.config`

Comment: @pquest -- The migration in question was not added with the "add-migration" command.

Comment: @JohnS: did you set an initializer?